# My user profile picture registration is not working on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a user registration form on the CodeIgniter framework so users can registrate to my website. Now the only thing that doesn't work is that I cant upload a profile picture. When I click on the register button I'm getting 2 errors. I want the profile picture to be uploaded in the product_foto column.

This is my view file: (register.php) :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="voornaam">Voornaam</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="voornaam" id="voornaam" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="achternaam">Achternaam</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="achternaam">Straat en huisnummer</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="straat" id="straat" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="huisnummer" id="huisnummer" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="huisnummer">Huisnummer</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="huisnummer" id="huisnummer">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="postcode" id="postcode">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="woonplaats" id="woonplaats">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email adres</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="emai">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" type="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="wachtwoord">Herhaal wachtwoord</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="wachtwoord2" id="wachtwoord" type="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="profiel_foto">Profiel foto</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="profiel_foto" id="profiel_foto">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="beschrijving">Beschrijving</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="beschrijving" id="beschrijving">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="geboortedatum">Geboortedatum</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="geboortedatum" id="geboortedatum" type="date">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="geslacht">Geslacht</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="geslacht" name="geslacht">
            <option value="Man">Man</option>
            <option value="Vrouw">Vrouw</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="register">Registreren</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the register code in the controller:

```
public function register() {

    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->input->post('profiel_foto');
    $data_upload_files = $this->upload->data();

    $image = $data_upload_files['./upload/'];

    //voeg gebruiker toe aan database
    $data = array(
        'voornaam'      => $_POST['voornaam'],
        'achternaam'    => $_POST['achternaam'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'wachtwoord'    => ($_POST['wachtwoord']),
        'startdatum'    => date('Y-m-d'),
        'postcode'      => $_POST['postcode'],
        'huisnummer'    => $_POST['huisnummer'],
        'woonplaats'    => $_POST['woonplaats'],
        'beschrijving'  => $_POST['beschrijving'],
        'geboortedatum' => $_POST['geboortedatum'],
        'geslacht'      => $_POST['geslacht'],
        'profiel_foto'  => $image
    );
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);

    $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Uw account is nu geregistreerd, u kunt nu inloggen");
    redirect("auth/register", "refresh");
}
```

And these are the 2 errors I'm getting when I'm trying to registrate:

```
 PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: ./upload/

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 131

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Auth.php
Line: 131
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once




A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'profiel_foto' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `users` (`voornaam`, `achternaam`, `email`, `wachtwoord`, `startdatum`, `postcode`, `huisnummer`, `woonplaats`, `beschrijving`, `geboortedatum`, `geslacht`, `profiel_foto`) VALUES ('hallo', 'hallo', 'hallo@gmail.com', 'hallo', '2017-06-28', 'hallo', 'hallo', 'hallo', 'hallo', '2017-06-10', 'Man', NULL)

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 149
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you read the user guide on this, even if you have already...https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html?highlight=upload#file-uploading-class and take another look at this.

Comment: Can you just tell me what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your First error is being caused by:

```
$image = $data_upload_files['./upload/'];
```

As stated './upload/' is not a valid index nor is an existing one in that array. It's not clear where you have defined that.

Next: What does this line do?

```
$this->input->post('profiel_foto');
```

Next: Debug: Inspect your array $data prior to the insert and check it.

```
// Snip of other code
    $data = array(
        'voornaam'      => $_POST['voornaam'],
        'achternaam'    => $_POST['achternaam'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'wachtwoord'    => ($_POST['wachtwoord']),
        'startdatum'    => date('Y-m-d'),
        'postcode'      => $_POST['postcode'],
        'huisnummer'    => $_POST['huisnummer'],
        'woonplaats'    => $_POST['woonplaats'],
        'beschrijving'  => $_POST['beschrijving'],
        'geboortedatum' => $_POST['geboortedatum'],
        'geslacht'      => $_POST['geslacht'],
        'profiel_foto'  => $image
    );
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    var_dump($data);
    exit();
// Snip of other code
```

And read the user guide as I stated above in my comments... Cause I aint writing that out here for you... That should get you started.